# Как применить валидацию на javascript к input radio

Tags: javascript, html, input, radio

Хочу сделать валидацию к `input` `radio` на `javascript` где требуется обязательный выбор одного варианта. Вот код на html

```
<form action="#" onsubmit="return validate()">
<div class="memory_type">
          <span id="warning"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i></span>
          <span class="details" id="error_memory">Тип памяти</span>
          <input
            type="radio"
            id="SSD"
            name="memory_type"
            value="1"
            selected="selected"
          /><label for="SSD">SSD</label>
          <input type="radio" id="HDD" name="memory_type" value="2" /><label
            for="HDD"
            >HDD</label
          >
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так например:

```
function validate() {


const memory = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="memory_type"]');
  const selected = [...memory].some((radio) => radio.checked);
  if (!selected) {
    error_memory.style.color = '#E52F2F';// менят цвет текста на красный
  }
  return selected;

 }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: сработало спасибо